# How to create an MySQL Database using NetBeans?

Tags: mysql, netbeans, jdbc

I want to check whether this database, "genericDatabase" is available among MySQL databases using NetBeans, and if not, I want to create this given database, with the tables using NetBeans(With the use of JDBC).

```
create database genericDatabase;
use genericDatabase;

create table data(
dataID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
dataName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (dataID)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

create table information(
informationID VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
informationName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (informationID)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

**I made an controller class with the SQL above, but it doesn't work. How to do this properly? I need to know how to identify a SQL database using NetBeans and how to create the database and insert tables if the database isn't available?**

Comment: NetBeans use java, right? ;)

Comment: [REFERENCE](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that what Nimila is searching for is a way to manipulate a MySQL database with Netbeans in order to be able to write a Java program for some CRUD application.

With Netbeans you can not create a database. You can use the mysql command or MySQL Workbench in order to create the database schema.

After this you can add your tables and prepare everything in order to write your Java code.

Here are your two tables in a schema, oddly, called "zoot"...

[image]